# IEnumerable vs List while iterating a collection

Tags: c#

My question is basically what's a good programming practice. In case of IEnumerable each item is evaluated at a time where as in case of ToList the whole collection gets iterated before it starts the for loop. 
As per below code which function (GetBool1 vs GetBool2) should be used and why.

```
public class TestListAndEnumerable1
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        GetBool1();
        GetBool2();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void GetBool1()
    {
        var list = new List<int> {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

        foreach (var item in list.Where(PrintAndEvaluate))
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    private static bool PrintAndEvaluate(int x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hi from " + x);
        return x%2==0;
    }

    private static void GetBool2()
    {
        List<int> list = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

        foreach (var item in list.Where(PrintAndEvaluate).ToList())
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: GetBool1(): Create an enumerator and loop through, return matching results and run code block. GetBool2(): Create an enumerator return matching results, copy matching results to new list (assign more memory! perhaps a lot if the list is a list of value types!), create enumerator and loop through, and run code block. Which do you think is better?

Comment: For more on differences have a look at [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/829624/Know-your-collections-from-IEnumerable-to-List-and) ... ?

Answer (score 2):

The bahviour of the two loops is different. In the first case the Console will be written to as each item is iterated and evaluated, and a Sleep will occur between each Console.Write.

In the second case the Console Writes will also be evaluated, but these evaluations will all occur before the Sleeps - these occur only when all the PrintAndEvaluate calls have finished.

The second case enumerates the members of the list twice, allocating and fragmenting memory as it does so.

If your question is "which is most efficient" then the answer is the first example, but if you want to know "is there another more efficient method" then just use a loop like;

```
  for(int counter = 0 ; counter <= list.Count; counter ++)
    {
        if(PrintAndEvaluate(list[counter]))
        {
           Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
```

This prevents the construction of an instance of an Iterator class so does not contribute to heap fragmentation.

Comment: It's fortunate that you've mentioned _"but these evaluations will all occur before the Sleeps"_. What Sweeper's answer is missing here is that even though this question might seem like something as simple as "time and memory differences" there's actually more to it. It is important to keep in mind that if you don't call `ToList` or any other "materialization" for that matter, any changes to the underlying collection will be reflected between individual element evaluations. So should new items be added to the collection between the sleeps, those additions will be reflected...

Comment: ... which is not the case if you call ToList. In that case, no matter what happens to the original collection, those changes will not be reflected. This can both be desired and undesired depending on the situation, so there are cases when calling ToList is preferable, while in others, it isn't. One word as a hundred, it is _definitely_ not just about time and memory.

Answer (score 0):

`GetBool1` should be used.

The sole difference between the two methods is the presence of the `ToList()` call. Right?

Let's look at the significance of the `ToList` call by first reading its [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Creates a `List<T>` from an `IEnumerable<T>`.

This means that a new list will be created when you call `ToList`. As you may know, creating a new list takes time and memory.

On the other hand `GetBool1` does not have a `ToList` call, so it does not take as much time to execute.

Comment: The presence of the ToList actually changes the order of the code execution.

Answer (score -1):

GetBool1 is the better option. For the option2, even you convert the IEnumerable to List, when you call foreach it called the GetEnumerator again. But the differences are very little. I make a little change of your code to output the execution time:

```
 public static void Test()
        {
            var list = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                list.Add(i);
            }

            GetBool1(list);
            GetBool2(list);
            GetBool3(list);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void GetBool1(List<int> list)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch watcher = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

            watcher.Start();
            foreach (var item in list.Where(PrintAndEvaluate))
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
            watcher.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("GetBool1 - {0}", watcher.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }

        private static bool PrintAndEvaluate(int x)
        {
            return x % 2 == 0;
        }

        private static void GetBool2(List<int> list)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch watcher = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

            watcher.Start();
            foreach (var item in list.Where(PrintAndEvaluate).ToList())
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
            watcher.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("GetBool2 - {0}", watcher.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }
```

The output is:
[image]

Comment: Comparing methods that don't do exactly the same thing seems pointless. Also, benchmarking one single iteration seems suspect, specially when you don't even JIT the methods first.